# Is it possible to prepare a single server (not app) for horizontal expansion without virtualization?

Tags: linux, centos7, cluster, glusterfs

I've been looking at how to build Cent OS 7 clusters and have a Website I've built which I want to host on a colocated server. Right now all the services (postfix, apache, node.js, mysql) are running on the server I have and am running out of storage while testing large amounts of uploads.

I've looked into GlusterFS and KVM.

My ideal end goal is

1 node/load balancer accepting requests -> 1 node apache -> 1 node shared storage + 1 node mysql

Is there a setup possible with one server, which I can slowly migrate away from while implementing actual hardware servers to take care of the tasks OR should I just set everything up one server, and when I need it, shut down all the servers and implement the expensive setup?

To add to the twist, I don't really want to use KVM in the long run, because it limits some of the server power from what I've heard, and will need full CPU power of the additional servers i'll be adding in the future.

Thank you.

Comment: What does that mean: "it limits some of the server power from what I've heard"? That sounds like some bad Internet myth.

Comment: @MichaelHampton According to the "internets" the CPU is more efficient at processing data when it doesn't have to go through KVM. This article's #6 says that for example. http://www.serverwatch.com/server-trends/top-10-reasons-not-to-virtualize.html

Comment: Do you think the right choice would be to setup KVM on the initial server, separate the services into VM's, then add a new server, give it an IP and let it take over the task of what a VM would was doing?

Comment: There's always overhead in virtualization, but it's negligible these days. It's certainly not something you would seriously consider in deploying a web application. These are not often CPU bound, and processors are cheap anyway. What you need to consider is what the benefits of virtualization are.

Comment: I would recommend ignoring that article you linked.